# Postprint biology repository

Tags: arxiv, open-access, preprint, repository, biorxiv

I recently found out that [bioRxiv](https://www.biorxiv.org/), the main biology preprint server, actually does not allow postprints to be submitted (even if allowed by the journal) according to its [policy](https://www.biorxiv.org/about-biorxiv). This is in contrast to arXiv (after which biorxiv was modelled) which does allow submission of postprints.

To clarify, *preprints* are the authors' version of the paper prior to intial submission, and *postprints* are the authors' version of the paper which was accepted for publication (typically without the editing performed by the journal). The term "postprint" is a little confusing because the paper will often be accepted by the journal but not printed or released yet.

I can understand that these two types of manuscript are different and should probably be tagged differently, but I can't really see a significant benefit in not allowing postprint submission - after all they do provide access to otherwise paywalled information, often before it is actually published.

**I would be interested to know if there are any alternatives to bioRxiv which allow postprint submission.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the OSF preprints are postprints. OSF is a platform that unites several preprint servers, and the posting rules may vary from one provider to the other. You can check it here: https://osf.io/preprints/
Also, I can suggest checking individual servers. You can find a comprehensive community-curated list here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17RgfuQcGJHKSsSJwZZn0oiXAnimZu2sZsWp8Z6ZaYYo/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 3):

In the U.S., everything funded by the NIH is available on PMC after 6 months: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/ . It's not perfect, but it's a pretty good way to ensure accessibility.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this but unfortunately there are two problems it does not solve: (1) giving fast access to papers ; (2) postprints outside the US (thought there are some efforts to expand this https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/about/pmci/).

Comment: EuropePMC? http://europepmc.org/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Mariia Levchenko's answer ([OSF Preprint servers](https://osf.io/preprints/)).

[**Zenodo**](https://zenodo.org/) is an alternative server that is not solely restricted to biology subject-wise but does contain a lot of biology content. It accepts preprints, postprints, data, and software deposits. It is [hosted at CERN](http://about.zenodo.org/infrastructure/) so you can be confident of the sustainability of the service provided.